# How I can use smint to scroll top in my one page website?

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, smint

I'm making one page website and I want use Smint(jquery plugin) to scroll right section in my webpage. So I made navbar and when I click section1 at my navbar site scroll almost top but not top. My navbar position is fixed because I want it staying top when page I scrolling the page. Probably problem is because section1 is under the navbar. And when I click section2 it jump to section2 but section2 in navbar is not active? So any ideas how I can fix this problem.

```js
//jquery.smint.js
/*

SMINT V1.0 by Robert McCracken
SMINT V2.0 by robert McCracken with some awesome help from Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan) and mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)
SMINT V3.0 by robert McCracken with some awesome help from Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan) and mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)

SMINT is my first dabble into jQuery plugins!

http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/

If you like Smint, or have suggestions on how it could be improved, send me a tweet @rabmyself

*/


(function(){


 $.fn.smint = function( options ) {

  var settings = $.extend({
   'scrollSpeed'  : 500,
   'mySelector'     : 'div'
  }, options);

  // adding a class to users div
  $(this).addClass('smint');


    
  
  //Set the variables needed
  var optionLocs = new Array(),
   lastScrollTop = 0,
   menuHeight = $(".smint").height(),
   smint = $('.smint'),
         smintA = $('.smint a'),
         myOffset = smint.height();

      



  if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {
    var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed
   }

  if ( settings.mySelector ) {
    var mySelector = settings.mySelector
  };



  return smintA.each( function(index) {
            
   var id = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

   if (!$(this).hasClass("extLink")) {
    $(this).attr('id', id);
   }

   
   //Fill the menu
   optionLocs.push(Array(
    $(mySelector+"."+id).position().top-menuHeight, 
    $(mySelector+"."+id).height()+$(mySelector+"."+id).position().top, id)
   );

   ///////////////////////////////////

   // get initial top offset for the menu 
   var stickyTop = smint.offset().top; 

   // check position and make sticky if needed
   var stickyMenu = function(direction){

    // current distance top
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()+myOffset; 

    // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
    if (scrollTop > stickyTop+myOffset) { 
     smint.css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0,'left':0 }).addClass('fxd');

     // add padding to the body to make up for the loss in heigt when the menu goes to a fixed position.
     // When an item is fixed, its removed from the flow so its height doesnt impact the other items on the page
     $('body').css('padding-top', menuHeight ); 
    } else {
     smint.css( 'position', 'relative').removeClass('fxd'); 
     //remove the padding we added.
     $('body').css('padding-top', '0' ); 
    }   

    // Check if the position is inside then change the menu
    // Courtesy of Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan)
    if(optionLocs[index][0] <= scrollTop && scrollTop <= optionLocs[index][1]){ 
     if(direction == "up"){
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
      $("#"+optionLocs[index+1][2]).removeClass("active");
     } else if(index > 0) {
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
      $("#"+optionLocs[index-1][2]).removeClass("active");
     } else if(direction == undefined){
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
     }
     $.each(optionLocs, function(i){
      if(id != optionLocs[i][2]){
       
       $("#"+optionLocs[i][2]).removeClass("active");
      }
     });
    }
   };

   // run functions
   stickyMenu();

   // run function every time you scroll
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    //Get the direction of scroll
    var st = $(this).scrollTop()+myOffset;
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (st < lastScrollTop ){
        direction = "up";
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
    stickyMenu(direction);

    // Check if at bottom of page, if so, add class to last <a> as sometimes the last div
    // isnt long enough to scroll to the top of the page and trigger the active state.

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           smintA.removeClass('active')
           $(".smint a:not('.extLink'):last").addClass('active')
           
       } else {
        smintA.last().removeClass('active')
       }
   });

   ///////////////////////////////////////
        
         $(this).on('click', function(e){
    // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so the menu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
    var myOffset = smint.height();   

          // stops hrefs making the page jump when clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // get the hash of the button you just clicked
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

    

    var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).offset().top-myOffset;
    
    // Scroll the page to the desired position!
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);
    
    // if the link has the '.extLink' class it will be ignored 
     // Courtesy of mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)
    if ($(this).hasClass("extLink"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

   }); 


   //This lets yo use links in body text to scroll. Just add the class 'intLink' to your button and it will scroll

   $('.intLink').on('click', function(e){
    var myOffset = smint.height();   

    e.preventDefault();
    
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

    if (smint.hasClass('fxd')) {
     var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset;
    } else {
     var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset*2;
    }
    
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

    if ($(this).hasClass("extLink"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

   }); 
  });

 };

 $.fn.smint.defaults = { 'scrollSpeed': 500, 'mySelector': 'div'};
})(jQuery);









//call smint
$(document).ready( function(){
 
     $('.menubar').smint();
 
 
    });
```

```css
html{
 background: #84b6f4;
 
}


.box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 46px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 background-color: black;
 
 
}

.nav{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 46px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: arial;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 background-color: #18ac11;
}
.nav li{
 
 float: left;
 
 
}
.nav li a{
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover{
 background-color: #11740b;
 
}

/*smint active section*/

.active {
 background: #25aae1;
}

.section1{
 background: red;
 
}
.section2{
 background: blue;
 
}
.section3{
 background: yellow;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


    
    

 <body>
  <div class="menubar">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Selection1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Selection2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Selection3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
 

 
  
  <div class="section1">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section1</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section2">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section2</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section3">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section3</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are 2 fixes

1. scroll to the top

   html, body {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
   }
2. active menu item

   .menubar {
       height: 46px;
   }

---

```js
//jquery.smint.js
/*

SMINT V1.0 by Robert McCracken
SMINT V2.0 by robert McCracken with some awesome help from Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan) and mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)
SMINT V3.0 by robert McCracken with some awesome help from Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan) and mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)

SMINT is my first dabble into jQuery plugins!

http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/

If you like Smint, or have suggestions on how it could be improved, send me a tweet @rabmyself

*/


(function(){


 $.fn.smint = function( options ) {

  var settings = $.extend({
   'scrollSpeed'  : 500,
   'mySelector'     : 'div'
  }, options);

  // adding a class to users div
  $(this).addClass('smint');


    
  
  //Set the variables needed
  var optionLocs = new Array(),
   lastScrollTop = 0,
   menuHeight = $(".smint").height(),
   smint = $('.smint'),
         smintA = $('.smint a'),
         myOffset = smint.height();

      



  if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {
    var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed
   }

  if ( settings.mySelector ) {
    var mySelector = settings.mySelector
  };



  return smintA.each( function(index) {
            
   var id = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

   if (!$(this).hasClass("extLink")) {
    $(this).attr('id', id);
   }

   
   //Fill the menu
   optionLocs.push(Array(
    $(mySelector+"."+id).position().top-menuHeight, 
    $(mySelector+"."+id).height()+$(mySelector+"."+id).position().top, id)
   );

   ///////////////////////////////////

   // get initial top offset for the menu 
   var stickyTop = smint.offset().top; 

   // check position and make sticky if needed
   var stickyMenu = function(direction){

    // current distance top
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()+myOffset; 

    // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
    if (scrollTop > stickyTop+myOffset) { 
     smint.css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0,'left':0 }).addClass('fxd');

     // add padding to the body to make up for the loss in heigt when the menu goes to a fixed position.
     // When an item is fixed, its removed from the flow so its height doesnt impact the other items on the page
     $('body').css('padding-top', menuHeight ); 
    } else {
     smint.css( 'position', 'relative').removeClass('fxd'); 
     //remove the padding we added.
     $('body').css('padding-top', '0' ); 
    }   

    // Check if the position is inside then change the menu
    // Courtesy of Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan)
    if(optionLocs[index][0] <= scrollTop && scrollTop <= optionLocs[index][1]){ 
     if(direction == "up"){
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
      $("#"+optionLocs[index+1][2]).removeClass("active");
     } else if(index > 0) {
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
      $("#"+optionLocs[index-1][2]).removeClass("active");
     } else if(direction == undefined){
      $("#"+id).addClass("active");
     }
     $.each(optionLocs, function(i){
      if(id != optionLocs[i][2]){
       
       $("#"+optionLocs[i][2]).removeClass("active");
      }
     });
    }
   };

   // run functions
   stickyMenu();

   // run function every time you scroll
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    //Get the direction of scroll
    var st = $(this).scrollTop()+myOffset;
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (st < lastScrollTop ){
        direction = "up";
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
    stickyMenu(direction);

    // Check if at bottom of page, if so, add class to last <a> as sometimes the last div
    // isnt long enough to scroll to the top of the page and trigger the active state.

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           smintA.removeClass('active')
           $(".smint a:not('.extLink'):last").addClass('active')
           
       } else {
        smintA.last().removeClass('active')
       }
   });

   ///////////////////////////////////////
        
         $(this).on('click', function(e){
    // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so the menu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
    var myOffset = smint.height();   

          // stops hrefs making the page jump when clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // get the hash of the button you just clicked
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

    

    var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).offset().top-myOffset;
    
    // Scroll the page to the desired position!
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);
    
    // if the link has the '.extLink' class it will be ignored 
     // Courtesy of mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)
    if ($(this).hasClass("extLink"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

   }); 


   //This lets yo use links in body text to scroll. Just add the class 'intLink' to your button and it will scroll

   $('.intLink').on('click', function(e){
    var myOffset = smint.height();   

    e.preventDefault();
    
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

    if (smint.hasClass('fxd')) {
     var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset;
    } else {
     var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset*2;
    }
    
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

    if ($(this).hasClass("extLink"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

   }); 
  });

 };

 $.fn.smint.defaults = { 'scrollSpeed': 500, 'mySelector': 'div'};
})(jQuery);









//call smint
$(document).ready( function(){
 
     $('.menubar').smint();
 
 
    });
```

```css
html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

html{
 background: #84b6f4;
 
}

.menubar {
 height: 46px;
}

.box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 46px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 background-color: black;
 
 
}

.nav{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 46px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: arial;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 background-color: #18ac11;
}
.nav li{
 
 float: left;
 
 
}
.nav li a{
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover{
 background-color: #11740b;
 
}

/*smint active section*/

.active {
 background: #25aae1;
}

.section1{
 background: red;
 
}
.section2{
 background: blue;
 
}
.section3{
 background: yellow;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


    
    

 <body>
  <div class="menubar">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Selection1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Selection2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Selection3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
 

 
  
  <div class="section1">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section1</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section2">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section2</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section3">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Section3</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  
  
 </body>
```